# How to go from multidimensional array to one dimension maintaining the groups

Tags: r, arrays, merge

I have an array of 4 dimensions: location(3) x species(3) x Season(6) x Depth (2). Like this matrix 12 times.

```
Season = 1, depth =  1
    [A] [B] [C]
[a] 12  52  55
[b] 13  14  235
[c] 13  76  355
```

I would like to merge everything in one big matrix like:

```
Season = 1, depth =  1
    [A] [B] [C]
[a11] 12  52  55
[b11] 13  14  235
[c11] 13  76  355
[a12] 12  52  55
[b12] 13  14  235
[c12] 13  76  355
[a21] 12  52  55
[b21] 13  14  235
[c21] 13  76  355
...
```

and so on. The first number would refer to one extra dimension, and the second for the other one. Does it make sense? Any idea?

Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: Take a look into `?aperm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This transposes the array with `aperm` and then makes a matrix.

```
location = 3
species = 3
Season = 6
Depth = 2

set.seed(1)
myArr <- array(sample(1000, location * species * Season * Depth), dim = c(location, species, Season, Depth))
myArrPerm <- aperm(myArr, perm = c(1,3,4,2))

matrix(myArrPerm, ncol = species)
```

Comment: If it worked you can select this as a solution. You can also +1 all answers you think we're helpful